# Why do i receive an error while attempting to validate json?

Tags: php, json

So i am attempting to validate my php (Json) script within JSON lint. Would be greatly appreciated if anyone could please help, thankyou :) . Here's my code:

---

### PHP Script

```
<?php

$host = "mysql9.000webhost.com";
$user = "a6594978_shark";
$password = "password2";
$db = "a6594978_sharkdb";

$sql = "select * from sharks_info;";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response,array("user"=>$row[0],"beach"=>$row[1],"shark"=>$row[2],"size"=>[3],"quantity"=>$row[4],"time"=>[5])); 
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

### JSON lint error

---

```
< br > < table border = '1'
cellpadding = '2'
bgcolor = '#FFFFDF'
bordercolor = '#E8B900'
align = 'center' > < tr > < td > < font face = 'Arial'
size = '1'
color = '#000000' > < b > PHP Error Message < /b></font > < /td></tr > < /table><br / >
    < b > Parse error < /b>:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in <b>/home/a6594978/public_html/json_get_data.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br /> < br > < table border = '1'
cellpadding = '2'
bgcolor = '#FFFFDF'
bordercolor = '#E8B900'
align = 'center' > < tr > < td > < div align = 'center' > < a href = 'http://www.000webhost.com/' > < font face = 'Arial'
size = '1'
color = '#000000' > Free Web Hosting < /font></a > < /div></td > < /tr></table >
```

### Results (below lint error)

---

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
< br > < table borde
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Comment: The interesting part of the output is: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/a6594978/public_html/json_get_data.php on line 18`

Comment: yer after i fixed the thing i forgot it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set [3]. There should be $row[3]. The same with 5

Answer (score 1):

```
array("user"=>$row[0],"beach"=>$row[1],"shark"=>$row[2],"size"=>$row[3],"quantity"=>$row[4],"time"=>$row[5]
```

You have missed $row[3], $row[5]